# Using Java's built-in Set classes to count EACH(keyword) unique element in List values from a list

Tags: java, list, set

Given a list that could contain duplicates (like the one below), I need to be able to count Each(keyword) number of unique elements.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
list.add("M1");
list.add("M1");
list.add("M2");
list.add("M3");

set.addAll(list);
System.out.println(set.size());
```

How do I get the count each unique element from the List?
That means i want to know how many "M1" contains in List(list), how many "M2", etc.

```
The result should be the following:
2 M1
1 M2
1 M3
```

Comment: Suggested edit to the question title: "How to count the number of occurrences of items in a List?" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this (I didn't compile it, but it should get you going in the right direction):

```
List<String> list = ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
// Fill list with values....

for (String item:list) {
    Integer count = counts.get(item);
    if (count == null) {
        // This is the first time we have seen item, so the count should be one.
        count = 1;
    } else {
        // Increment the count by one.
        count = count + 1;
    }
    counts.put(item, count);
}

// Print them all out.
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getValue() + " " + entry.getKey());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `Map<String, Integer>` data structure, not `Set`

Something like

```
for(iterating over something){ 
    Integer count =map.get(value); 
    if( count == null){
          map.put(value, 1);


    } else{
        count++;
        map.put(value, count);
    }

}
```

Map is the data structure that maps unique to value

Comment: How do i count in Map? or in Map the same values are added?
I have never used Map before.)

Comment: I suggest refactoring the code to only call map.get() once per loop.

Comment: count++ looks fishy to me. It is an Integer, not an int. Does that really do what you want it to do? I think map.put(value, count + 1) would be a bit easier to read anyway...

Comment: count++ is valid with `Integer`

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that (it always looked fishy to me) :-)

Answer (score 2):

`Set` won't help you in this case, you need a Map:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
list.add("M1");
list.add("M1");
list.add("M2");
list.add("M3");

// ...

Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(String element: list) {
    int currentCount;
    if(counts.contains(element)) {
        currentCount = counts.get(element) + 1;
    } else {
        currentCount = 1;
    }
    counts.put(element, currentCount);
}

// ...

for(String element: counts.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("element: " + element + ", times appeared: " + counts.get(element));
}
```

Comment: I suggest refactoring this code to not call both contains() and get() in the same iteration. Also, the code as written counts repeats, not counting number of times each item appears in the list - put(element,0) should be put(element,1).

Comment: Also, your print loop doesn't need to call get() - just iterate over entrySet(). get/contains/etc. are pretty fast, but not free.

Comment: @Rob about your first comment: all valid, fixed. About your second comment: get() is actually called.

Comment: My second suggestion was to NOT call get(). You want to iterate over all entries in the Map and the most efficient way to do that is to iterate over entrySet(). This way, you don't have to evaluate the hashcode() and equals() method of each key as you call get() on each key. Map.Entry<K, V> is ugly, but it gets the job done with basically no overhead.

Comment: @Rob I'm not going to change that part because the code works anyway. But I'm going to upvote your answer as you spotted that first.

Answer (score 0):

means You want to know how many "M1" contains in List(list), how many "M2", instead of using **set** interface, you can use the  **Map** interface because Map contain the key, value pair format ,i.e.  Map data structure.

```
 Map<key,Value>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't say what to put in the map. Some more details on how a Map can be used to solve this problem would make this a more useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Much easier way: use `Collections.frequency()`

`System.out.println("M2: "+Collections.frequency(list,"M2");`

will output

`M2: 1`